# IAV Member login

Tags: yodlee

Does the member login feature in IAV require any separate settings to be enabled?

I was able to do a CoBrandlogin. Using the session token from cobrand when I try to do a member login, I am getting "Invalid User Credentials"

This is rest call is

https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login?cobSessionToken=08062013_2:b186c6c4dcac974227f273b9bc6dfc91daa90e2cfbc9699501545013096ff19f60b0493528fe682b5f5be40db145cf983e739b5034df02b3c1b5cb8238ff1c29&login=sbMem#####1&password=sbMem#####1#123

and the error is

"Error": [
        {
            "errorDetail": "Invalid User Credentials"
        }
    ]

I am using one of the 5 accounts from sandbox.

When I am try to do member login using the Yodlee API (for aggregate functions) it works but fails with the above error for IAV

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired clicking on the "Account Verification" if the logins are setup correctly by Yodlee then you will see the login screens for banks.

Answer (score 0):

For IAV we don't have to enable anything for User Login.

Can you please try again with the below mentioned data-

Request method: **POST**

URL: https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login

login: sbMem#####1

password: sbMem#####1#123

cobSessionToken: obtained cobrand session token.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik